# Как найти ближайшее четное число, меньше или равное данному?

Tags: php, алгоритм

Получаю число делением. Если четное — подходит, если нечетное — нужно изменить на четное, отняв единицу. Подскажите алгоритм решения.

```
$perPage = 18 / 2; //18 это просто пример, делить нужно и другие числа

echo $perPage; // дает 9, а требуется 8
```

Comment: А что при 19 / 2 должно вернуть?

Comment: И почему при делении 18/2 должно получиться четное число? Почему у этого вопроса уже три ответа? ААА!

Comment: Вам нужно придумать каким же именно образом из нечетных и дробных чисел получать четные. Вариантов масса.

Comment: Мы ответили, потому что поняли о чем автор спрашивает. А вы нет ;)

Comment: @Visman: а я отредактировал, чтобы каждый мог понять, а не только телепаты ))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Еще вариант:

```
<?php

$perPage = 18 / 2;

echo intval($perPage / 2) * 2;
```

**UPD** сделан после принятия ответа как правильный. В ответ на обсуждение в ответе от @Nick Volynkin.
Провел тестирование скорости работы того или иного варианта в такой конструкции:

```
$start = microtime(TRUE);

for ($i = 2; $i < 100000; $i++) {

// код примера

}

echo "time: ", microtime(TRUE) - $start, "\n";
```

1. Ответ от @Dmitriy Simushev, время выполнения **~ 0.60 сек**. Ответ от @Nick Volynkin имеет примерно такое же время (т.е. там где заменили двойное деление на 2 на одинарное но на 4).
2. Мой ответ, представленный выше, время выполнения **~ 0.54 сек**.
3. Ответ от @xaja, время выполнения **~ 0.10 сек**. Смотрите **UPD3**.
4. И наконец победитель ;) Спасибо @VladD'у за напоминание об этом способе:

   ```
   <?php

   $perPage = 18 / 2;

   echo (int)($perPage / 2) * 2;
   ```

Время выполнения **~ 0.08 сек**.

**UPD2** По поводу правильности решения:

1. Если автор работает только с положительными числами, то все ответы перечисленные в UPD дают верный результат;
2. Если на входе есть как положительные числа, так и отрицательные и получить всегда надо ближайшее четное, меньшее или равное данному, то единственный правильный ответ - это ответ от @xaja; Смотрите **UPD3**.
3. Если же надо получить ближайшее четное по модулю, то правильными ответами являются все кроме ответа от @xaja.

**UPD3** Ответ от @xaja в таком виде

```
$perPage = 18 / 2;

$odd = ($perPage % 2 != 0);

if ($odd) {
    $perPage--;
}

echo $perPage;
```

выдает ошибочный результат для нечетного числа на входе.

Comment: Предпочел этот ответ, так как в нем наименьшее число операций, возвращается целое число и предусмотрено возвращение четного от любого числа присвоенного вначале.

Comment: Plush, на самом деле в ответе @xaja операций (действий интерпретатора после компиляции исходного кода во внутреннее представление) меньше, поскольку вызов функции дороже, чем непосредственные вычисления.

Comment: @avp в ответе господина xaja результат дает дробную часть, чтобы получить целое число придется вызывать функцию округления.

Comment: Обновил свой ответ.

Comment: У меня времена несколько другие получились и вариант с `$perPage = 18 / 2; $perPage = $perPage - $perPage % 2;` оказался несколько быстрее остальных (по времени очень близко к варианту @VladD)

Comment: Где вы такой вариант увидели среди ответов? Опубликуйте его как ответ ;)

Comment: Нет, лучше не публикуйте :) Для 19, ваш вариант возвращает 8.5, а не 8.

Comment: это не мой вариант, это вариант @xaja, я его просто ускорил немного, т.е. баги в "моем" варианте - это баги в его/ее варианте

Comment: Спасибо за обнаружение бага. Я как то пропустил его при тестировании ответа от @xaja.

Comment: Мой вариант (сам придумал) #1: `$perPage = ($page - $page % 4) / 2;`, вариант #2 (оптимизированный @NickVolynkin): `$perPage = $page >> 2 << 1;` - где-то в полтора раза быстрее, чем у @VladD ))

Comment: @BOPOH, оформите ваш комментарий как ответ, пожалуйста. Ваш первый вариант показывает примерно 0.089 сек в тесте, второй с побитовым сдвигом ~ 0.07 сек.

Comment: Да, и второй вариант на -18 выдает -10, то есть работает не по модулю, выводит четное число, равное или меньше.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26690/discussion-between-bopoh-and-visman).

Answer (score 5):

Например так:

```
$perPage = 18 / 2; // может быть и (19 / 2)

echo (floor($perPage / 2) * 2); // выведет 8
```

Comment: UPD зря добавили. Он у вас ни чего не меняет.

Comment: Хм... да, конечный результат будет действительно тот же. Хотя по-моему код стало проще понять.

Comment: Понятнее он точно не стал, так как он и до этого был элементарный.

Comment: убрал лишний UPD =)

Comment: Данный пример тоже дает верный результат, правда в нем вы использовали функцию для работы с добью - деление на 2 не всегда возвращает число с дробью, но благодарю и вас. UP

Comment: `floor` в явном виде указывает на округление (в меньшую сторону). `intval`, с другой стороны, чаще используется для приведения к целочисленному типу (не только дробных чисел, но и строк, логических величин, ...). Хотя результат действительно будет один и тот же.

Answer (score 4):

```
$perPage = 18 / 2;

$odd = ($perPage % 2 != 0);

if ($odd) {
    $perPage--;
}

echo $perPage;
```

Comment: Это ошибочное решение. При 19 в ответе будет 8.5, а не 8 как должно быть.

Comment: вы правы, но ничего не мешает округлить в нужную сторону. в данном случае просто было показано как провести проверку "на четность"

Answer (score 4):

> Как найти ближайшее четное число, меньше или равное данному?

На операциях деления и умножения на степени двойки наиболее эффективен побитный сдвиг ([arithmetic shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Arithmetic_shift)). ([спасибо @BOPOH за код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/440278/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83/440281#comment462515_440281))

- Сдвиг влево на `n` эквивалентен умножению на `2n`

  ```
  a = $x << 2;
  b = $x * 4;
  echo (a == b) //true
  ```
- Сдвиг вправо на `n` эквивалентен делению на `2n`

  ```
  a = $x >> 2;
  b = $x / 4;
  echo (a == b) //true
  ```

Если отбросить то, что переменная сначала еще раз делилась на два и отвечать на общий вопрос, то достаточно сдвиг вправо и влево на 1 бит:

```
even = $number >> 1 << 1;
```

Поскольку в конкретном примере переменная предварительно делилась на два, то мы можем сделать упрощение. Зачем дважды делить на 2, если можно один раз делить на 4?

```
perPage = $page >> 2 << 1;
```

Если без сдвига, то можно обойтись простой арифметикой.

```
perPage = floor($X / 4) * 2;
```

Comment: Вызов функции в интерпретаторе просто убивает всю эту незатейливую оптимизацию.

Comment: Это, естественно, про `intval()`

Comment: Нет, разницы не будет. Надо как в ответе @xaja проверить результат деления на четность и для нечетного уменьшить на единицу.

Comment: Коллеги! Я думаю, если уж рассуждать о скорости арифметических операций, стоит сначала уйти от PHP и обратиться к более _продвинутым_ языкам. Потому что сейчас мы обсуждаем, кто лучше бегает: дельфин или кит.

Comment: Опять дело не в этом, а в вызове функции, которая будет *обязана* проверять тип аргумента, на что, по сравнению со всей остальной арифметикой интерпретации байткода выражений и условного перехода будет затрачено намного больше машинных инструкций. Что же  насчет времени деления и умножения в интерпретаторе, то imho об этом можно особо не заботиться на фоне всех накладных расходов по интерпретации байткода (все это размажется по конвейеру при переупорядочивании исполняемых машинных инструкций в современном CPU (ведь наверняка все исполняется на каком-нибудь xeon-е)).

Comment: @VladD, вообще-то, с практической точки зрения Вы совершенно правы. (просто сейчас совсем не осталось обсуждений всяких технических тонкостей и проч. интересных штучек).

Comment: @avp: спасибо, понял. Поставил плюс ответу xaja.

Comment: Вроде бы можно воспользоваться конструкцией `(int)`, она не выглядит как вызов функции. (Но я не знаю наверняка, я ни на копейку не разбираюсь в PHP.)

Comment: Обновил свой ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Если число в целочисленном формате и реализовано допкодом, то надо почистить младший двоичный разряд. Это делает операция
`$x & -2`

Answer (score 2):

Ну раз деление не нужно, можно двумя сдвигами:

`$a = $a >> 1
$a = $a << 1`

Если предположить что максимальное целое в PHP - 0xFFFFFFFF, то можно вообще одной операцией младший бит сбросить:
`$a = $a & 0xFFFFFFFE`

Comment: Первый вариант [уже есть](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/440349/181472), можно и в одну строку. :) А вот с `&0xFFFFFFFE` интересная идея. А какое время выполнения?

Comment: Не заметил со сдвигами, много букв уже написано :-) Сброс младшего бита на x86/x64 должен выполняться очень быстро, это одна инструкция. Как это будет на PHP с его интерпретатором - не знаю, но думаю тоже быстро. Хотя, учитывая "особенности" некоторых кусков кода PHP - не факт...

Comment: кстати, там же еще отрицательные в этих 4х байтах как-то записываются. Так что не факт, что `0xFFFFFFFF` это наибольшее, надо бы разобраться, где там нужный бит.

Comment: @NickVolynkin И так сработает: сбрасывается только младший бит из 32, в нем точно нет знака.

Comment: 0xFFFFFFFE - зависит от количества и порядка байтов в формате числа

Answer (score 2):

Округление до четного числа вниз - это очистка младшего двоичного разряда:

`$x & ~1`

Округление до четного числа вверх - это добавление 1 и очистка младшего разряда:

`($x + 1) & ~1`

Comment: [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/440415/5079) похожее использовали, только ~1 за вас выполнили, за счет чего там скорость выше. Но у вас зато универсальнее - вдруг php где-нить 128-битный стоит ))

Comment: первая операция ничего не делает

Comment: @ВОРОН в случае PHP Вы правы, и тэг стоит. А как с переносимостью на другие языки?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$a=18;
if($a % 2 == 0){
   $c = ($a / 2) - 1;
}else{
   $c = $a / 2;
     }
echo $c;
?>
```

Comment: В принципе, это работает, плюсанул. Но можно значительно оптимизировать. Рекомендую вам посмотреть на новые ответы, тут много способов предложили. :)

Comment: Спасибо, обязательно изучу предложенные варианты. Я только начал изучать программирование, поэтому изложил ответ так как сделал бы сам сейчас. Надеюсь в дальнейшем буду находить более актуальные ответы

Comment: "только начал изучать программирование" — если еще можете, переключайтесь на любой другой язык. Java, C#, Python, JS, C++, Ruby... PHP, по многочисленным мнениям, необратимо ломает мозги )))

Comment: @Nick что вы подразумеваете под "необратимо ломает мозги"?